# как заблокировать доступ по ftp без использования .ftpaccess

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp

Как можно на сервере заблокировать доступ по ftp, сохранив при этом доступ по ssh без использования .ftpaccess?

Answer (score 1):

- Остановить ftp сервис и оключить автозагрузку(
  через `>systemctl stop nameFTP.service && systemctl disable nameFTP.service`)
- Закрыть порт ftp в iptables (`>iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j DROP`)
- Удалить службу ftp ( тут в каждом дистре по разному)